# How to upload Video from computer in CMS Page in magento-1.9?

Tags: video, magento-1.9

I am trying to upload video in CMS Page and static block, but video is not uploaded. 
I recheck the video format i.e. Mp4 . 
Please tell me how to upload a video in CMS Page?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create a module that edits the configuration you find at `app/code/core/Mage/Cms/etc/config.xml` on line 123.

you have to create a new module for example `Himani_Video` that contains the following xml:

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <Himani_Video>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </Himani_Video>
    </modules>
    <adminhtml>
        <cms>
            <browser>
                <extensions>
                    <media_allowed>
                        <mp4>1</mp4>
                    </media_allowed>
                </extensions>
            </browser>
        </cms>
    </adminhtml>
</config>
```

This will allow you to upload mp4 videos from the backend:
[image]

Comment: What is not working for you? Can you provide more information so maybe I can point you in the right direction?